# Is there anyway to add condition in function of parameters?

Tags: php, sql

I have a grid where I need to have some filters in.
Actually I have only 2 parameters available but the thing is that I will have maybe 5/6/7 or even more and I need a good way to manage it in my json encoding.

I manage it by this way :

```
if(!empty($_GET['q']) && empty($_GET['s'])) {
        $client = $_GET['q'];

    $requeteDevis = myPDO::getInstance()->prepare(<<<SQL
            SELECT SC_libelle, ETP_libelle, DVS_numDevis, DVS_libelle, DVS_montant, DVS_statut, DVS_pourcent, DVS_montant,
            USR_Nom, USR_Prenom, CTC_Nom, CTC_Prenom, ctc.idContact, DVS_date
            FROM Utilisateur usr, Devis dvs, SiteClient sc, Client clt, Contact ctc, Entreprise etp
            WHERE usr.idEntreprise = etp.idEntreprise
            AND usr.idUtilisateur = dvs.idUtilisateur
            AND dvs.idSiteClient = sc.idSiteClient
            AND sc.idClient = clt.idClient
            AND dvs.idContact = ctc.idContact
            AND clt.CLT_libelle = ?
SQL
);


    $requeteDevis->execute(array($client));    
} else if (!empty($_GET['s']) && empty($_GET['q'])) {
$stat = $_GET['s'];

    $requeteDevis = myPDO::getInstance()->prepare(<<<SQL
            SELECT SC_libelle, ETP_libelle, DVS_numDevis, DVS_libelle, DVS_montant, DVS_statut, DVS_pourcent, DVS_montant,
            USR_Nom, USR_Prenom, CTC_Nom, CTC_Prenom, ctc.idContact, DVS_date
            FROM Utilisateur usr, Devis dvs, SiteClient sc, Client clt, Contact ctc, Entreprise etp
            WHERE usr.idEntreprise = etp.idEntreprise
            AND usr.idUtilisateur = dvs.idUtilisateur
            AND dvs.idSiteClient = sc.idSiteClient
            AND sc.idClient = clt.idClient
            AND dvs.idContact = ctc.idContact
            AND dvs.DVS_statut = ?
SQL
);



    $requeteDevis->execute(array($stat));
}
    else if ......
```

So, do you think there is any way to have only one sql statement ? Else it will finish I will have 50 ones :/

Thanks

Comment: Please also show what you would do with your sql code depending on the conditions, so that we see your full logic/pattern in your code

Comment: done, it just adds / removes a condition in function of parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find how to manage it :

Here is the code :

```
if(empty($_GET['s'])) { 
            $state = null;
        } else $state = $_GET['s'];

        if(empty($_GET['q'])) {
            $client = null;
        } else $client = $_GET['q'];


        $requeteDevis = myPDO::getInstance()->prepare(<<<SQL
            SELECT SC_libelle, ETP_libelle, DVS_numDevis, DVS_libelle, DVS_montant, DVS_statut, DVS_pourcent, DVS_montant,
            USR_Nom, USR_Prenom, CTC_Nom, CTC_Prenom, ctc.idContact, DVS_date
            FROM Utilisateur usr, Devis dvs, SiteClient sc, Client clt, Contact ctc, Entreprise etp
            WHERE usr.idEntreprise = etp.idEntreprise
            AND usr.idUtilisateur = dvs.idUtilisateur
            AND dvs.idSiteClient = sc.idSiteClient
            AND sc.idClient = clt.idClient
            AND dvs.idContact = ctc.idContact
            AND (dvs.DVS_statut = :statut OR :statut is null)
            AND (clt.CLT_libelle = :client OR :client is null)
SQL
);  

        $requeteDevis->execute(array(":statut" => $state,
                                     ":client" => $client));
```

So with only one request, you are able to manage every filters. thanks for help tho

Answer (score 0):

```
$cond1 = '';
$cond2 = '';
$cond3 = '';
$var = 2;
if(1==2){
$cond1 = ' AND column1>20';
}
if(3==3){
$cond2 = ' AND column2 < '.$var;
}
$cond3 = ' ORDER BY id DESC';
$baseSQL = "SELECT  * FROM table WHERE 1=1 $cond1 $cond2 $cont3";
```